# getting parse error with (T_IS_EQUAL)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here am getting an error while using this code in server and but not in localhost.

```
<?php if(!empty($assign_tool_info) && !empty($assign_tool_info->type == "engineer")) { ?>
```

Here is the error 
 `parse error:Message: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either checking if `$assign_tool_info->type` is not empty and equal to `engineer`. You need to do that separately

```
if(!empty($assign_tool_info) && !empty($assign_tool_info->type) &&  $assign_tool_info->type == "engineer") {
```